# Графика в играх на Android

Tags: android, java

Как и в чем делается вся эта красивая графика для игрух на андроиде? 
Не просто нарисованые ПНГшки.

Очень интересно все это узнать, если будут еще и русско язычные статьи, так вообще премного благодарен :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Забудьте про русские статьи. В 2д играх - пнгшки, в 3д - полноценный OpenGL ES 2.0

- [2D Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)
- [3D with OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)

И посмотрите примеры игр из апи. Там всё довольно подробно описано.